# I can't hover only one element with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-hover

As I said in title my problem is I can't hover just one element. I gave some effect but each element is affected. I know it's a simple question and I search google and stackoverflow, I found. But any solution is working.

İn the codes are here: https://jsfiddle.net/dty0wth0/

Also I tried that too:

```
  $("section#box").mouseenter(function() {
             $('section#box span').css({'transition':'1s','top':'80px'}); 
        }).mouseleave(function() {
              $('section#box span').css({'transition':'1s','top':'-80px'}); 
        });
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: there are no images. poor example

Comment: no need. I want to effect just text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an addressing problem.

This hovers the div (entire image), and only works with the span.

```
$("section#box div").hover(
   function() {
      $('span', this).css({'transition':'1s','top':'80px'})
   }, 
   function() {
    $('span', this).css({'transition':'1s','top':'-80px'}); 
   }
);
```

Although, frankly, this should just use CSS transitions entirely:

```
section#box div {
    position: relative;
}

section#box div span {
    top: -80px;
    transition: all 1s;
    position: absolute;
}

section#box div:hover span {
    top: 80px;
}
```

Comment: nice - should have thought of CSS first before my answer - well done :))

Comment: Thanks, It's works.But I can't understand very well. What is difference to 'span,this' and 'section#box span,this'. I mean this.

$('span', this).css({'transition':'1s','top':'80px'})

It's works. And 

$('section#box span', this).css({'transition':'1s','top':'80px'}).

It isn't works. What is difference ? And again thank you :).

Comment: `$('span', this)` means look for all spans that are children of the current context of `this`.  In our case, it will be whichever `div` under `#box` was hovered.  `$('#xbox div').hover()` can only have one element at a time, which takes that context of `this`.  Without `this`, you have no idea which div was the event target without doing further event processing.

Answer (score 0):

use jQuerys hover which handles both the mouse in function and hte mouse out function:

```
$("section #box").hover(
  function() {
     $('section #box span').css({'transition':'1s','top':'80px'})} 
  ,function() {
     $('section #box span').css({'transition':'1s','top':'-80px'}); 
   }
);
```

also you could proabably use $(this).find('span') inside the hover functions to target the span to the #box that is focussed.

Comment: Firstly thanks for helping. But I know how to hover on element. I just can't hovering only one element. İf I use like this, each element affected.

Comment: then its a case of specificity on the hover function - use $(this).find() to target an element inside the parent element that is hovered.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have a lot of syntax errors (missing comma after function, extra parentheses)
2. You have a lot of unnecessary code (section selector, extra *this* context)
3. You need to include a library that has that method (for instance, jQuery) as you did not attach jQuery to your fiddle

#### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dty0wth0/7/)

```
$("#box").on('mouseenter mouseleave', 'div', function(e) {
  var $target = $('span', this);

  if (e.type == 'mouseenter') {
    $target.css({ transition: '1s', top: '80px' });
  } else {
    $target.css({ transition: '1s', top: '-80px' });
  }

});
```

When the div is hovered (e.g., *mouseenter*, *mouseleave*) call the in/out function.  Inside the in/out determine if it was the enter or leave event and apply the CSS to the target span inside the div.

This is actually the better solution because you're binding one event handler to the #box, instead of to each div or span.  Once the box is hovered, it checks to see if the target (div) was hovered and if so, calls the function.

Inside the function, the target for the effect is span.  *this* points to div, so simply find the span within the *this* (div) context and apply the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment so Ill do it here...
I guess you will need to do is showen here:

https://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/

Answer (score 0):

You should add the span to your main selector then your mouseenterer and mouseleave will be wrapped in that context.

```
$("section #box span").mouseenter(function() {
             $(this).css({'transition':'1s','top':'80px','text-size':'25px'}); 
        }).mouseleave(function() {
              $(this).css({'transition':'1s','top':'-80px','text-size':'12px'}); 
        });
```

Comment: two problems with this is first - you have not corrected the typos her (section#box ) - it needs a space separating the section and the id and second your answer would only trigger the hover on the actual span - - sucky if its only a glyphicon or other small element.

Comment: Thanks for helping. But I can't hover the text, When I hover the box, I want  to affected text.

Comment: To change the text you Have to add some CSS that target text.